# Why java is not suitable to develop some big computer 3Dgame?

Tags: java

C# depends on XNA to develop some 3Dgames but can java devlop some 3dgames why?

Comment: You can write 3D games in Java if you choose.

Comment: Unfortunately this question doesn't meet the minimum requirements for this site, such as having a definite answer. You have also gotten several answers with comments that are at best opinions (like the ones about speed.) If you can pinpoint a more specific question, feel free to re-ask it, but I'm closing this one as subjective and argumentative. This is basically a bike-shed question.

Comment: This 3D game is written in Java: http://tribaltrouble.com/

Answer (score 12):

You can write 3D games in java if you want, biggest example is minecraft... It's a little buggy and at times a little slow... but it's still written in java

Comment: +1 for MineCraft :-)  And bugs and slowness have less to do with Java and more to do with implementation issues.

Comment: +1 again for MineCraft...it is buggy but then it's still in Beta!

Answer (score 5):

Wurm Online is developed in java and, though doesn't have the greatest cutting edge graphics looks and performs quite well. You might want to check it out and investigate some of the libraries and such used. You can learn a lot from just playing with the setup of it. So, my answer would be yes you can use Java.

Comment: Is Wurm open source? That would be interesting to look over.

Comment: That would be interesting for sure, but it is not, no.

Comment: That's a shame. There are always decompilers, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a game in any language java was originally used on most mobile phones for games and i believe android is based on java.

Java is also pretty handy in the Multi-threading arena which again improves game performance.
However due to java nature (being run in an run time environment the JRE) it can be pretty sluggish.

The are some 2d and 3d libraries made for java which include

- [lqjgl](http://lwjgl.org/) - A 2d and 3d game library
- [JMonkey Engine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/) - Again 2d and 3d
  (primarily 3d) library based on
  openGL